# Google Maps V3 removing event listener not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am plotting a number of polygons from an array and then adding three event listeners to each one; mouseover, mouseout and click all of which are working as expected and only effecting the specific polygon.

What I need is to disable the mouseout event when a click event occurs so that the colour change which occurs with the click is not removed by the mouseout.

Having read lots of posts here and in other places I have tried adding a handle to the mouseout event listener and then adding google.maps.event.removeListener(listentothis); to the click listener but it doesn't work.

I have also tried google.maps.event.clearListeners(chartLayer, 'mouseout'); but that isn;t working either.

Full code can be seen at http://testsite.imray.com/mapsv2.php

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as it is doing my head in and I can't see why it won't work.

Thanks

Code as requested:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
            chartLayer  = new google.maps.Polygon({
                series: chartData[i].seriesID,
                paths: chartData[i].latLngs,
                map: map,
                strokeColor: chartData[i].colour1,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: chartData[i].colour2,
                fillOpacity: 0,
                activeOutline: chartData[i].colour3,
                activeInterior: chartData[i].colour4,
                itemcode: chartData[i].itemcode,
                itemname: chartData[i].itemname,
                itemlink: chartData[i].itemlink,
                itemscle: chartData[i].itemscle,
                itemedtn: chartData[i].itemedtn
            });
            imrayLayer.push(chartLayer);

            google.maps.event.addListener(chartLayer, 'mouseover', function() {
                this.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: this.activeOutline,
                    fillColor: this.activeInterior, 
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                });
            });

            var listentothis = google.maps.event.addListener(chartLayer, 'mouseout', function() {
                this.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: this.strokeColor,
                    fillOpacity: 0
                });
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(chartLayer, 'click', function() {
                google.maps.event.removeListener(listentothis);
                this.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: this.activeOutline,
                    fillColor: this.activeInterior, 
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
                });
                var text = '<h3>' + this.itemname + '</h3>';
                text = text + this.itemscle + this.itemedtn;
                text = text + '<p class="mbot5"><a href="' + this.itemlink + '" title="View full product details" target="_blank">View product page</a></p>';
                text = text + '<form action="" id="addForm" name="addForm"><input type="hidden" id="ItemCode" name="ItemCode" value="' + this.itemcode + '" /><p class="bold">Add to basket <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="addtobasket()" title="Add this chart to your basket" /><img src="files/images/buy-arrow.png" style="vertical-align:middle;" /></a></p></form>';
                text = text + '<div id="message"></div>';
                showInSideDiv(text);
            });

            chartLayer.setMap(map);
        }
```

Comment: Better post the relevant code here or make a fiddle in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace google.maps.event.removeListener(listentothis); by google.maps.event.clearListeners(chartLayer, 'mouseout');

Comment: Tried that Seb but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you overwrite `chartLayer` and `listentothis` on every loop, so when you click on a polygon it will always affect the last created polygon(or event) inside the loop.

You may easily use `this` inside the click-callback to access the clicked polygon:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(chartLayer, 
                              'click', 
                              function() {
                                google.maps.event.clearListeners(this,'mouseout');
                              });
```

(Note that the method is called `clearListeners`, not `removeListeners`, as mentioned by Seb P's comment)