# Google Maps: Remove all click events on event trigger

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a function that loops an array of markers and assigns click events to all of them.

```
for(var key in markers){
    clickEvent(markers[key], sekolah[j].show, sekolah[j].hide, key);
}

function clickEvent(mark, showArr, hideArr, key){
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
        //does a lot of stuff
    });
}
```

What I would like to do is to remove/disable **all** click events when any marker has been clicked (so that no two markers can be clicked sequentially without resetting the map first). The click events would be enabled again when the user resets the map.

This is the function to reset the map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
    setAllMap(map);             //Shows all markers
    //and a lot of stuff
});
```

I have tried using `addListenerOnce`, but that didn't work. I have also tried this suggestion from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109144/google-maps-v3-removing-event-listener-not-working), but the result was the same as using addListenerOnce.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you.

PS this is how I created `markers`:

```
var newMark = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    id: ids,
    title: name,
    icon: "res/schoolf.png"
});;
markers[ids] = newMark;
```

Comment: Have you tried `google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');` ?

Comment: @juvian I have. It ended up behaving like I was using 'addLisstenerOnce'.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: My guess is that you need to iterate through your array of markers calling `google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker]i], 'click');` for i from 0 to the last marker.